# Generate PDF reports from an opensearch dashboard with filters via API?

Tags: python, opensearch

I have a dashboard with all users and certain metrics.

To generate a report for a specific user I need to filter the dashboard for that particular user and then go to reporting>generate report as PDF.

I’d like to do this programmatically but can’t seem to find any documentation on how to go about it. Is this possible with python?

Comment: If scheduled reports works for you check this: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/reporting/report-dashboard-index/#creating-reports-using-a-definition

Comment: I need to add a filter to the dashboard though so if I have 10,000 users this would be 10,000 dashboards

Comment: With one dashboard but different authorization each customer can only see their data. check this: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/access-control/document-level-security/#parameter-substitution